# Razor pages Identity

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I've a Asp.NET Core 3.1 MVC Application with Identity and E.F..

Im personalizing the IdentityUser with ApplicationUser and i need to change values in Identity Razor Pages for example the page `Identity/Account/Manage` but thoose page is not in my project.

I've generated scafolding with command `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MVCCallHub.Data.ApplicationDbContext` but was created only login, register and logout page.

Where is the other Identity Pages?

My pages structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Microsoft Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization

You'll see that the command has a `--files` parameter and with this you can choose which files you want to scaffold, this is the example in the docs:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyWeb.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"
```

If you run the `aspnet-codegenerator` with `--listFiles` you'll see the available list of files that can be scaffolded:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles
```